# best practice for name putExtra

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent, kotlin

i use Intent.putExtra("name",value).
i have a issue whith name parameter in putExtra function.

I have 3 or more ways:

1 - use direct string -> Intent.putExtra("name",value)

2 - use static final in class

```
public final static KEY = "name";
Intent.putExtra(KEY,value)
```

3 - defined in string.xml in value folder

```
<resources>
    <string translatable="false" name="name">name</string>
</resources>
```

and use this way

```
 Intent.putExtra(getResource().getString(R.string.name,value)
```

which way is better than others?

Comment: Use a static and constant (final) string.. If you need to use in different places, you can make it public. This way, you ensure same key will be used when writing/reading that extra

Comment: Number 1 is bad because you have to reference it in multiple places, and there's a chance you typo it.  Number 3 is bad because there's 0 value in putting it in strings, it just requires you to do extra work.

Comment: @GabeSechan use number 2? Is static variable not bad? why number 3 is bad? can you explain more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your situation, however,  if you have to reference the same value multiple times, static is usually the way to go.

here's why : using local string variables leave the risk of you making a mistake when you type it , as well as having to update every single reference to that string when you make a change in your code, meaning it's not flexible or easily modified.

storing it in strings.xml is not the correct way of doing it, as this file is specifically made for android localization and having to do a call to getResources every time will make life difficult when you do not have a reference to context .

From the android developer guides, they even make use of static string values as part of their examples for intents.

[image]

Comment: if I use translatable="false" for string xml, the text not translate

Comment: this photo for action, not for key in intent for pass data local app

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to create new class/interface named IntentConstants.java and inside it put -
public final static KEY_NAME = "name";
....

Which can be easily accessible as,
IntentConstants.KEY_NAME

that's it. Also you can store in strings.xml but I will not prefer it as it contains all views related strings also you have to write too much code and it will be mess too. That's my opinion. :)